# InvalidCastException System.DBNull cannot convert to System.Byte[] - BLOB File

Tags: c#, oracle, exception

I wanted to export blob files to my filesystem with an OracleReader. It works for most of them but I get a System.DBNull exception with some.

The Exception is thrown at "byte[] byteArray = (Byte[])myReader["DATEIBLOB"];"

can I get around this with a if-query?

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(oracleBlobSqlString))
    {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = oraCon;

    OracleDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        //Pfad
        string sqlPath = myReader.GetString(1);
        string sqlFilename = myReader.GetString(0);


        byte[] byteArray = (Byte[])myReader["DATEIBLOB"]; //Exception

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream((pPath + "/" + sqlPath + "/" + sqlFilename), FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            fs.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }

        if (exportToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            cancelToken = true;
        }
    }
    myReader.Close();
    logFile("Dateiblobs nach " + pPath + " exportiert");
}
```

Comment: Simply checking for `DBNull.Value` before casting would be my way to solve this. Something like: `byteArray = myReader["DATEIBLOB"]==DBNull.Value?null:(byte[])myReader["DATEIBLOB"]`.

Comment: It works perfectly. I was accidentally in the wrong function earlier when I wrote that it didn't work. Today I have a worm in there ... German proverb. xD Thank you very much, Mr. Keim.

Comment: Sehr gerne. Gruß aus Süddeutschland 